# Restart hive service on AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, emr

I am very new to HIVE as well AWS-EMR. As per my requirement, i need to create Hive Metastore Outside the Cluster (from AWS EMR to AWS RDS). 
I followed the instruction given in

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-dev-create-metastore-outside.html

I made changes in hive-site.xml and able to setup hive metaStore to Amazon RDS mysql server. To bring the changes in action, currently i am rebooting the complete cluster so hive start storing metastore to AWS-RDS. This way it is working.

But i want to avoid rebooting the cluster, is there any way i can restart the service?

Answer (score 15):

Just for those who are gonna come from Google

To restart any EMR service

In order to restart a service in EMR, perform the following actions:

1. Find the name of the service by running the following command:

   initctl list

For example, the YARN Resource Manager service is named “hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager”.

2. Stop the service by running the following command:

   sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
3. Wait a few seconds, then start the service by running the following command:

   sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager

Note: Stop/start is required; do not use the restart command.

4. Verify that the process is running by running the following command:

   sudo status hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager

Check for the process using ps, and then check the log file for any errors in the log directory /var/log/.

Source : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/

Answer (score 3):

```
 sudo stop hive-metastore
 sudo start hive-metastore
```

Answer (score 2):

On EMR 5.x I have found this to work:

`hive --service metastore --stop`

`hive --service metastore --start`

Answer (score 1):

For me this approach worked:

1. Get the pid
2. Kill the process
3. Process restarts by itself

Commands for 1 & 2:

```
ps aux | grep MetaStore
sudo -u hive kill <pid from above>
```

Here if you are not familiar with `ps` you can use the following command which will show the headers for `PID` and only one line of the hive Metastore command:

```
ps aux | egrep "MetaStore|PID" | grep -v grep
```

Hive Server restarted by itself. Validate again by `ps` the pig would have changed.

```
ps aux | grep MetaStore
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to restart the entire cluster. While launching the cluster, you can specify a hive-site.xml file with the details of RDS. If you are not following this option and making the changes manually after launching the cluster, you don't need to restart the entire cluster. Just restart the *hive-metastore* service alone. Hive metastore is running in the master node only

You can launch the cluster either by using multiple ways.

1) AWS console
2) Using API (Java, Python etc)
3) Using AWS cli

You can keep the hive-site.xml in S3 and perform this activity as a bootstrap step while launching the cluster. AWS api is providing the feature to specify custom hive-site.xml from S3 rather than the one created by default.

If you are using hive from the master machine alone, you don't have to make the changes in all the machines.

An example of specifying the hive-site.xml while launching EMR using aws cli is given below

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Test cluster" --ami-version 3.3 --applications Name=Hue Name=Hive Name=Pig \
--use-default-roles --ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey \
--instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 \
--bootstrap-actions Name="Install Hive Site Configuration",Path="s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script",\
Args=["--base-path","s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/hive","--install-hive-site","--hive-site=s3://mybucket/hive-site.xml","--hive-versions","latest"]
```

Comment: I have stored hive-site.xml in AWS s3 but unable to create new cluster. it gets terminated after some seconds. i followed AWS documentation. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-dev-create-metastore-outside.html).

Comment: @hadron sudo stop hive-metastore
sudo start hive-metastore